# How to make input field take up 100% of the unused space?

Tags: html, css

I've been spinning my wheel on this little thing for hours now.
I have a div. In that div, I want two buttons on the right-hand side (side-by-side) and the rest of that row filled in by an input field. I've tried countless combinations of CSS options and I can't figure it out.
I need item1 and item2 to be side-by-side and taking up the entire width of the parent div.
Any ideas from the CSS gurus?  Thanks!!

http://jsfiddle.net/vasxmg1d/

```
<div style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; height: 300px;">
    <br/>
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <input id="item1" type="text" style="width: 100%"/>
        <div id="item2">
            <button>button1</button>
            <button>button2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display:block;` on your CSS may do the trick.

Comment: so you want the input box and both buttons all on the same line?

Comment: @mason81 Yes, exactly. But I should clarify that this is just an example. The item1 parent will be varying widths, so I'm looking for a general solution whereby item1 will fill in 100% of the remaining width regardless of the size of its parent.

Comment: @JimOtt you have 2 syntax error from your code `</br>` and `<div id="item2">*</table>`

Comment: @Nabi you mean `</button>` - had me confused there :)

Comment: @Nabi  Argh. Sorry about that. Brain was fried after a long day!  Fixing it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Modern approach - flexbox

Use flexbox - set the wrapper `<div>` to `display: flex` and the `<input>` to `flex: 1` (effectively `flex-grow: 1`):

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
#item1 {
    flex:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vasxmg1d/10/

More info on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

#### Older approach - table layouts through CSS

If you prefer to use table layouts, at least do it through CSS instead of introducing table markup in your HTML (but you will need to add a wrapper element around your input to achieve it)

http://jsfiddle.net/vasxmg1d/12/

```
<div id="item1">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
}
#item1,#item2 {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#item1 {
    width: 100%;
}
#item1>input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cound using `tables` also

Follow this:

```
<div style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; height: 300px;">
    <br/>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
        <td width="100%"><input type="text" style="width: 100%;box-sizing:border-box;"/></td>
        <td><button>button1</button><br><button>button2</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sheesh.. This would have worked too. I don't know why I didn't think of this. So obvious now. I accepted the other answer, because CSS is typically the 'preferred' way of doing things these days?  Even though I like this better because I can actually understand it. lol

Comment: @JimOtt i also upvoted `CupawnTae` answer because a css solution ( But my code in better on old browsers )

Comment: @JimOtt FYI you can change your accepted answer if you prefer this one. But there are good reasons for preferring CSS for purely layout purposes over tables, and flexbox is well worth reading about :-) Either way, I won't be offended if you want to change

Comment: I'm reading up on flexbox now. Good stuff. Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: @JimOtt and Nabi I've added an alternative to my answer that illustrates how to use table layouts without having to introduce table elements into the HTML markup

Answer (score 1):

Not to sure if I get your question. Nevertheless, I just played around with the percentages. Check out the JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/vasxmg1d/2/

```
<input id="item1" type="text" style="width: 65%"/>
```

I placed a perctange on your button so they can fit.

```
button{
    float:left;
    width:15%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Kadeem. Thanks for your reply. My fault for not being more clear in my post. The item1 block needs to be 100% because its parent may be varying widths. What I gave here is just a simplified example.  So even though item2 can be a fixed width, item1 will need to shrink and grow to fill in the remaining space regardless of the width of their parent.

Comment: Ok I see, no worries mate good question. And you got your answer in the end. :)

Answer (score 0):

Position the buttons to the right using `float: right`. Set the width of the textbox using `width: calc(100% - x)` where `x` is the width of the buttons:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: calc(100% - 122px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you don't know the width of the buttons, you can get it with JavaScript:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelector(".buttons");
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=text]");
input.style.width = "calc(100% - " + buttons.offsetWidth + "px)";
```

```css
.box {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.buttons {
    float: right;
}
input[type=text] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <input type="text"/>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button>button1</button>
        <button>button2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```